# How to enable audio offload in Jetpack Compose Media3 Exoplayer in ver. 1.2

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer, android-media3

In version 1.1 (and backwards) there was an option to offload audio with `.setEnableAudiOffload` in `Exoplayer.Builder`.

In version 1.2 they removed it and they only mentioned this:

> Offload can be enabled through setAudioOffloadPreference in `TrackSelectionParameters`. If the set preference is to enable, the device supports offload for the format, and the track selection is a single audio track, then audio offload will be enabled.

But how and where do we use `TrackSelectionParameters`? Remains unclear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is the right solution, but I found an API like this:

```kotlin
exoPlayer.trackSelectionParameters = exoPlayer.trackSelectionParameters
    .buildUpon()
    .setAudioOffloadPreferences(
         AudioOffloadPreferences
             .Builder()
             .setAudioOffloadMode(AudioOffloadPreferences.AUDIO_OFFLOAD_MODE_ENABLED)
             .build()
    )
    .build()
```